# Hovering on the drop down the options is merged behind the container, how do i get the drop down options displayed over the container

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hovering on the drop down (Categories, Sortby), the options is not view able behind the container, how do i get the drop down options displayed over the container

```
.container {
    margin: 25px auto;
    position: relative;
    width: 800px;
    height:800px;
    background-color: #D8D8D8;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px; 
}
h1 {
    text-align:center;
}

}
.categories {
    float: left;    
}
.sortby{
    float: center;  
}
.search{
    float:right;
}    
.container1 {
    position: relative;
    top: 150px;
    left: 200px;
    bottom: 300px;
    right: 400px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    position: absolute;
    width: 50%;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border: solid 1px #0076a3;     
}
```

Plese find the code of HTML and CSS in my fiddle link below:
https://jsfiddle.net/testnew/fne7njrb/

Comment: Normally you could use `z-index` but you have `container1` embedded in `container`.  You need to think this through - if you want the background behind everything, you need to separate it from the menu (or the menu will be behind everything as well).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the z-index css property on your drop down menus. Then they will be visible over the other elements. Like this:

```
  li ul {display: none;z-index:5;}
```

I hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

Set the z-index for the drop down UL:

```
li ul {
  display: none;
  z-index: 100; <--- Set this
}
```